# How to deal with this JSON?

Tags: json, swift

I have this JSON coming from server:

```
{
  "models": [
    {
      "code": "RPX",
      "name": "Tank",
      "color": null,
      "alias": [
        "tank"
      ],
      "plantCode": "FR",
      "countryName": "France",
      "plantAlias": null,
      "plantGroup": "5",
      "matrix": [
        {
          "size": "BIG",
          "union": null
        }
      ],
      "imageURL": "https://example.com/tank.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

from this JSON I have built this model:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct ModelDecode: Codable {
    let models: [Model]?
}

// MARK: - Model
struct Model: Codable {
    let code, name: String?
    let color: JSONNull?
    let alias: [String]?
    let plantCode, countryName: String?
    let plantAlias: JSONNull?
    let plantGroup: String?
    let matrix: [Matrix]?
    let imageURL: String?
}

// MARK: - Matrix
struct Matrix: Codable {
    let size: String?
    let union: JSONNull?
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        // No-op
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

Then I have this to decode the JSON:

```
final class ListOfTanks:NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
  
  private let session: URLSession = NetworkService.shared.getSession()
  private let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  private let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  
  static let shared = ListOfTanks()
  
  static func serverURL() -> URL? {
   let getServerHost = "https://example.com/request"
   let getServerPath = "/getTanks"
    
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "https"
    components.host = getServerHost
    components.path = getServerPath
    guard let url = components.url else { return nil }
    return url
  }
  
  
  static func getRequest() -> URLRequest? {
    guard let url = ListOfTanks.serverURL()
    else { return nil }
    
    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("service", forHTTPHeaderField: "iPad")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    return request
  }
  
  func getStations(completion:callback<ModelDecode>?) {
        
    guard let request = ListOfTanks.getRequest() else {
      completion?(.failure("Failed to build request"))
      return }
    
    let session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
                                         delegate: self,
                                         delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
      
      guard let data = data else {
        completion?(.failure("Error"))
        return
      }
      
      do {
        let result = try self.decoder.decode(ModelDecode.self, from: data)
        completion?(.success(result))
      } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
        completion?(.failure("Error Parsing Error \(String(describing:error))"))
      }
  
    }
    task.resume()
    
  }
  
}
```

the JSON is retrieved correctly but the last `try` for decoding fails with:

```
typeMismatch(MyApp.JSONNull, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "models", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "matrix", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "union", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull", underlyingError: nil))
failure("Error Parsing Error typeMismatch(MyApp.JSONNull, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: \"models\", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: \"Index 1\", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: \"matrix\", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: \"Index 1\", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: \"union\", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: \"Wrong type for JSONNull\", underlyingError: nil))")
```

How do I solve that?

NOTE: I have omitted some code that I think is implicit, once the JSON is being retrieved correctly. If you need some specific code, please ask.

Comment: in `getStations`, add `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` just before the `do {...}`
 and show us what you are **really** getting from the server. You could try replacing all your `JSONNull?` with `String?`.

Comment: Observation; you may need to have `let getServerHost = "example.com/request"`, since you already have `components.scheme = "https"`

Comment: I thing you used some online tool to help create your JSON model, hence the introduction of `JSONNull`, I might suggest you to temporarily remove all JSONNull and then try parsing. Post that enable one JSONNull param at a time to understand which is failing, then parse that item appropriately.

Comment: Don’t make everything optional by default, it’s a bad habit. Side note, it’s very strange that you have a type that represents null and that properties of that type are declared optional! A null that can be null itself, some kind of metaphysics? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is get rid of that `JSONNull` type. It´s not helping. This type will fail to decode as soon as the JSON value is something different then `null`. And a property that allways stays `null` seems kind of pointless.

Next step would be to replace the `JSONNull`s with their "real" type as an optional. Multiple approaches here

- Get a better sample. As you seem to have created this structs by [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/), paste a larger dataset into it. There´s a good chance this will give you the types you need.
- Make an assumption. As all of the properties seem to be of type `String` it would be **(kind of)** safe to assume the missing ones are of the same type. Replace `JSONNull` with `String?`
- Ask/Read. Read the docu or contact the owner/developer of the API and ask what types there are and wich one could get `null`.

Comment: Yes, I was generating the code by using `quicktipe.io` and super many big hyper thanks, changing `JSONNull` to `String?` did the trick. It is working now. THANKS.